# Prevent elements from jumping around in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

Check out the page at http://myhymnal.net/2. In Chrome when the page loads every other element between the title and the lyrics (the key selector and the links) seems to move around a little. Same happens when you hover over the two sections. Seems to be related to the opacity and/or CSS transition?

As far as I can see, this only happens in Chrome and I don't understand what's going on here as it works perfectly fine in both FireFox, Opera and IE.

Is there something off about my CSS or markup? Or is it a bug in Chrome? Or what's going on here? Any way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: just guessing, did you try to add fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `font` declaration from :

```
body, input, textarea, select {
    font: 120%/1.5 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;
}
```

to

```
body, input, textarea, select {
    font: 100% 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;
}
```

it seems like all your elements are scaling according to this as they have measurements set in `em`.

I could be wrong about the description, but the solution works :)

Comment: Hm, that does get rid of the jiggle, but also makes the font smaller, which is kind of what I was trying to counteract by making the font bigger :p Any idea why this solves it? Am I increasing the font size incorrectly somehow?

Comment: I think so yes, give it a larger `px` value